# Which OS X programs can rapidly find and replace text in very large files?

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation

I am looking for a macintosh program that can find and replace text in a very large text file (7MB). I've tried TextMate, TextEdit and nano (command line) but both take a very long time (I've waited over an hour and still didn't finish). Am I being impatient, or is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: 7MB doesn't seem very large to me and 1 hour does seem like a long time. Is that compressed or uncompressed? Is the find and replace just that or are you using Regular Expressions?

Comment: What is slow, the loading of the file or the search/replace operation? Using Unix commands like `sed` would be a good alternative for big files but if you need help here please add some examples for strings to be searched and replaced.

Comment: As a benchmark I just used BBEdit to do a simple find and replace on a 30MB text file.  Was so fast it didn't have time to draw a progress bar. This is on a 2.9 Ghz i7 iMac.

Comment: The file is uncompressed, and the loading of the file search/replace operation is extremely slow. I'll try BBEdit, it looks promising!

Comment: @patrix - My first thought was `sed` too, and then I saw the 7MB comment. 7MB is **not a large file**. I have 1GB+ log files floating around, and even *those* really aren't that large. My first thought is a poorly optimized regex.

Comment: I know that 7MB isn't a large file, but judging by how my computer was acting, it was :o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My question was solved by AllInOne: Download BBEdit. The time to search and replace went down from 1 hour+ to about five seconds.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use [Text Wrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) (the free incarnation of the full featured BBEdit) for working on text files that are too large for other tools.

Comment: Same thing.  BBEdit is the paid version of TextWrangler with a few more features... either of them do not suck.

Comment: Well, I'll be darned. Didn't know that.